# How to pass python list slice without copying?

Tags: python, list

I wrote a quick select algorithms as below:

```
def partition(arr):
    pvt = 0
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
        if arr[i] < arr[-1]:
            arr[i], arr[pvt] = arr[pvt], arr[i] # mv smaller elements before pvt
            pvt += 1
    arr[-1], arr[pvt] = arr[pvt], arr[-1]
    return pvt

def quickselect(k, arr):
    p = partition(arr)
    while k != p:
        p = partition(arr[:p]) if k < p else partition(arr[p:])
    return arr[k]
```

What I intend to do is to find the kth element in an arr with O(n) complexity. But when I finished the coding, I found that arr[:p] actually pass a copy rather than a slice of original list, which will not make the recursive partition work properly. As far as I know, pandas Series slice actually did what I want. If I pass arr as pd.Series, it seems to work properly. But is there a more native way to pass an origin slice of python list arr[:p] ?

Comment: Slicing a list *always* produces a new list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arr[:p]` *is* a copy, so there's no way to pass it without copying.

---

As you already discovered, you can use a different type that does "view slicing"—`memoryview`, `np.array`, `pd.Series`, etc.

---

Or you can pass the whole list and the slice information around together, like this:

```
def partition(arr, start, stop):
    pvt = 0
    for i in range(start, stop - 1):
        if arr[i] < arr[stop-1]:
            arr[i], arr[pvt] = arr[pvt], arr[i] # mv smaller elements before pvt
            pvt += 1
    arr[stop-1], arr[pvt] = arr[pvt], arr[stop-1]
    return pvt

def quickselect(k, arr, start=None, stop=None):
    if start is None: start = 0
    if stop is None: stop = len(arr)
    p = partition(arr, start, stop)
    while k != p:
        p = partition(arr, start, p) if k < p else partition(arr, p, stop)
    return arr[k]
```

---

Or you can write a simple wrapper that carries around the list, start, and stop values and implements `collections.abc.Sequence` (or `MutableSequence`) by forwarding appropriately. That's more work up-front, but it might make the other code you're writing more readable.

You can find a simple version of mutable and immutable slice views [here](https://github.com/abarnert/slices). It's not as thoroughly tested as I'd hoped, but it seems to work for your `quickselect`. (Of course the cost for linear rather than quadratic work is probably swamped by the constant multiplier of building a wrapper object for each slice until you get to decent-sized lists…)

Comment: Thank you for detail anwser, making more parameters will always work. Can you please share more about memoryview? Interesting one.

Comment: @Pythoner [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typememoryview) gives you a way to view-slice bytes-like objects, or fancier objects that support the buffer protocol. It won't do you any good with lists (lists don't support the buffer protocol), but with huge buffers stored as `bytes` or `bytearray`, or giant `array.array`, `mmap`, etc., it can be handy. Usually you're better off with numpy or pandas than anything you can do with `memoryview`, but not always (e.g., sometimes you're on a machine where you can't install numpy…).

Comment: Your SliceView handles slices of slices incorrectly; the `start`, `stop`, and `step` generated for a slice of a slice are relative to the first slice, not the original sequence. [Here's an example](https://ideone.com/5yKfUP) (adjusted a bit because Ideone doesn't have f-strings). The base SliceView and the first slice are correct, but slicing a slice selects the wrong elements.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, when stripping out the error handling to make it more concise, I also stripped out the lines that add `self.start` to `start` and `stop`… Should be fixed now. But maybe it would be better to clean up the library I have on github and just post a link to that?

Comment: That probably depends on what you have on Github. (Your revised answer is better, but it looks like it's still missing some `step` handling. [Here's an example](https://ideone.com/ZwFsMM) - both the first slice and the subslice show the wrong elements.)

Comment: Maybe it would be simpler to use `range` objects which seem to know most of the slicing arithmetic necessary. To give a random example `range(2, 12, 3)[-2::-2]` -> `range(8, -1, -6)`

Comment: @user2357112 What I have on GitHub includes unit tests. And mutating (only single values and equal-length slice assignment, of course). It’s part of another project, and relies on a general-purpose slicing helper, but cleaning it up is probably easier than rewriting it on the fly. (It’s probably worth noting that I never found an actual use for it, except as a demonstration of the slicing helper library…)

Comment: @PaulPanzer As it turns out, my helper library did rely on ranges, which is pretty obvious now that I think about it (and obviously I _did_ think about it however many years ago I wrote it…). Anyway, I've now separated it out into its own project and updated it a bit. Although the tests aren't nearly as complete as I'd hoped…

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use numpy or pandas as well as stated by Mr. abarnert. But importing package will not always work for pure algo questions.

```
import numpy as np

def partition(arr):
    pvt = 0
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
        if arr[i] < arr[-1]:
            arr[i], arr[pvt] = arr[pvt], arr[i] # mv smaller elements before pvt
            pvt += 1
    arr[-1], arr[pvt] = arr[pvt], arr[-1]
    return pvt

def quickselect(k, arr):
    arr = np.array(arr)
    p = partition(arr)
    while k != p:
        p = partition(arr[:p]) if k < p else partition(arr[p:])
    return arr[k]
```